# How can i create a melody? Is there any sound-module?

Tags: python, audio

I am confused because there are a lot of programms. But i am looking something like this. I will type a melody like "a4 c3 h3 a2" etc. and then i want to hear this. Does anybody know what i am looking for?
thanks in advance

Comment: "h3"?  Apart from the h3, your notation resembles the notation used by lilypond.  Look for a lilypond-to-audio or lilypond-to-midi app.

Comment: Ah, Location: Berlin.  As I suspected.  @Ewan: in German music notation, it's "cdefgah". "h" instead of (english/international) "b".

Comment: Nitpick: as I understand it, "H" is actually we we call B flat - B (natural) is still just B. The composer Bach was able to use this to encode his name in notes into one of his pieces.

Comment: Close, Daniel. German B equals U.S. B flat (Bb), and H equals B.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

computing frequencies from note name is easy. each half-note is 2^(1/12) away from the preceding note, 440 Hz is A4.

if by any chance you are on windows, you may try this piece of code, which plays a song through the PC speaker:

```
import math
import winsound
import time

labels = ['a','a#','b','c','c#','d','d#','e','f','f#','g','g#']
# name is the complete name of a note (label + octave). the parameter
# n is the number of half-tone from A4 (e.g. D#1 is -42, A3 is -12, A5 is 12)
name   = lambda n: labels[n%len(labels)] + str(int((n+(9+4*12))/12))
# the frequency of a note. the parameter n is the number of half-tones
# from a4, which has a frequency of 440Hz, and is our reference note.
freq   = lambda n: int(440*(math.pow(2,1/12)**n))

# a dictionnary associating note frequencies to note names
notes  = {name(n): freq(n) for n in range(-42,60)}

# the period expressed in second, computed from a tempo in bpm
period = lambda tempo: 1/(tempo/60)

# play each note in sequence through the PC speaker at the given tempo
def play(song, tempo):
    for note in song.lower().split():
        if note in notes.keys():
            winsound.Beep(notes[note], int(period(tempo)*1000))
        else:
            time.sleep(period(tempo))

# "au clair de la lune"!! 'r' is a rest
play( 'c4 c4 C4 d4 e4 r d4 r c4 e4 d4 d4 c4 r r r '
      'c4 C4 c4 d4 e4 r d4 r c4 e4 d4 d4 c4 r r r '
      'd4 d4 d4 d4 A3 r a3 r d4 c4 B3 a3 g3 r r r '
      'c4 c4 c4 d4 e4 r d4 r c4 e4 d4 d4 c4 r r r ', 180 )
```

(please note that i am using python 3.x, you may need to adapt some part of the code in order to use it on python 2.x.)

ho, by the way, i used `abcdefg` as a scale, but you will surely find the way to use `h` instead of `b`.

Comment: NameError: global name 'names' is not defined

Comment: ooops, sorry. that's what happen when you don't clear your python session before testing. corrected now !

Answer (score 3):

One outside option is [JFugue](http://www.jfugue.org/) as [shown here](http://codetojoy.blogspot.com/2008/01/mytunes-groovy-and-jfugue.html) (with Groovy). Note that you would use [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) instead of Python, which hopefully is within bounds as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

you could use any library that produces MIDI output, in case of .net I'd recommend
 the one created by Stephen Toub from Microsoft(can't find from where i got it, but google for it.)

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: http://www.algorithm.co.il/blogs/index.php/pytuner/
It's a very similar projet and looks like a very decent reference.

Comment: i have trouble with installing pymedia :(